# How to add additional gems inside a RubyGem package?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, package

I am going through the documentation at http://guides.rubygems.org/ to learn about RubyGems.

My goal is to package a Ruby application (no executables) which depends on some other Gems (for example, say, Rails!).

I am not a Ruby expert so I am confused and have the following two questions:

1. How can I add the Gem inside the package to be shipped with my app?
2. Should I instead not add the gem inside but create dependencies list, which is to be executed upon  installation of my gem?
3. What is the right way to ship dependencies with my gem?

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to specify dependencies in your gemspec file. Have a look at rails.gemspec as an example for help on syntax: https://github.com/andhapp/rails/blob/master/rails.gemspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each gem has a gemspec file where the dependencies are specified. Use bundle to install the gem and it will also install the dependencies.